# Searching for polygons which have certain location using MongoDB

Tags: point-in-polygon, mongodb

I am trying to implement a search feature on MongoDB using Mongoose.js , the short version of which is this:

**I tag locations on a map as polygons. and give them names. Then when an user searches for a place using coordinates, I check which polygon the location falls within, and return the polygon.**

I know that the reverse of what I am trying to do works by specifying a polygon, and then searching for locations which fall within the polygon, but I am looking for the opposite.

So instead of saying:

```
var polyA = [ [ 10, 20 ], [ 10, 40 ], [ 30, 40 ], [ 30, 20 ] ]
query.where('loc').within.polygon(polyA)
```

I want to say

```
var 'loc' = [ 11, 24 ]
query.where(loc).within.polygon('polygon')
```

where `'polygon'` is a polygon schema.

I believe it might be possible to do this with mongoDB 2.4 as it'll support GeoJSON, but is it currently possible to do it with mongoDB 2.2?

**What I've thought of so far**

I think it might not be possible even with MongoDB 2.4. So I'm thinking of using some linear algebra to solve this.

1. I compute the center of the polygon, and store it with the polygon area.
2. Then when I search the database I find a polygon with the center/area-point within a certain distance of the location.
3. Loop through each two points in the polygon, and set an `y <?> m(x) + c` type constraint, store the constraints in a JavaScript object.
4. Check if location coordinates satisfy the constraints, and return false if any of them is not satisfied. Else return true if satisfied.

In effect I'm drawing a polygon's restrictions, and checking if the said location meets all of these. The problem here's that if I have complex polygons (which I'll more likely have) the test would take longer to return an answer.

**On reinventing the wheel**

*I sometimes get reprimanded for 'reinventing the wheel' by using MongoDB instead of a proper GIS database, which normally has some of the features I ask about. I am aware that what I am trying to do is what has probably been solved years ago by RMDBS, but I want to do it in Mongo.
One prevalent way which this feature is likely already implemented is in geocoding, because to find the town/state/country which a point lies in, one would do the above. I thus sincerely want to try to do this in MongoDB as it complements the other computations that I'm already performing in Mongo.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB 2.4 has support for this, so I ended up upgrading. The documentation was not very clear at the time (during pre-release), but the feature works using `$geoWithin` on Polygon GeoJSON objects.